# Universal way to share images to other apps

Tags: java, android, sharing

I'm developing an app which can send an image to other apps. After Nougat was released we should use `FileProvider`. But I noticed that this approach is not universal. For earlier versions of Android we should use `Uri.getUriFromFile()` method. But using `FileProvider` also doesn't work on Nougat for some apps (i.e. default messages app). Is there any universal method which will work with all apps, or I should define apps which can't work with `FileProvider` only on practice?

Comment: "I'm developing an app which can send an image to other apps" -- do you mean `ACTION_SEND`? "i.e. default messages app" -- there are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across thousands of device models. There is no single "default messages app", but rather dozens or hundreds of them.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I mean `ACTION_SEND`. About default messages app, I mean app which help send MMS and SMS

Answer (score 0):

Following code must work properly:

```
    File file = new File(filePath);

    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.example.fileprovider", file);

    if (contentUri != null) {

        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // temp permission for receiving app to read this file
        shareIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, getContentResolver().getType(contentUri));
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);


        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image");

    }
```

Comment: Is the main thing `shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);`?

Comment: No, this is not a required parameter. I have use this code at API 21 and less and it worked well

Comment: Strange. Because of in my case it doesn't work for some devices on Lollipop, Marshmallow and KitKat Android versions.

Comment: if you use `FileProvider` you must add  `shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);` because otherwhise other apps do not have read permissions for your private app dir where `FileProvider` reads the data from